# Setting Maven environment variable

Tags: java, maven, cmd

I been trying to set the Maven environment variable, but it's not liking it. I don't know why, I've triple checked everything and it should be working.

Here is the error I got:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME not found in your environment variable.
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation
```

And here are my variables:

```
JAVA_HOME ---> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26
MAVEN_HOME ----> C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.0.5

Path ----> C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin
```

Sorry if my path file is a little long. Basically the important part is that I did indeed put them in right, they should both be at the very end. What else could have gone wrong?

Also to clarify a little bit, I did check that the file is indeed where I specify it to be. And I know my Java version should be right, when I do a:

```
javac -version
```

in cmd I do get the right version.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `M2_HOME` instead of `MAVEN_HOME` in the path and environment variable

`M2_HOME ----> C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.0.5`
and `%M2_HOME%\bin` in path

Answer (score 1):

As you are using a jdk/maven path with space in between so try using the path in quotes such as :
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26"

Or

simply dump the java and maven in non-space directories as it avoids such problems. I generally put java in C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_26 and mavin in C:\maven\maven3.0.

Try either of the solutions and you should get lucky :-)

Answer (score 1):

And please ensure to put the JAVA_HOME environment variable inside the system environment variables and not the user environment variables.
Don't forget to restart your shell after you changed environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse then set VM arguments in JRE as

```
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=true
```